# Linq To SQL help on OR condition

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two tables:

**Company**

<sub>Note: `AliasList` values are separated by semicolons</sub>

```
CompanyID | CompanyName | AliasList                                          
-------------------------------------------------------
1         | Wal-mart    | Walmart;Wal Mart;Samsclub
```

**Empl**

```
EmplID | EmployerName
-------------------------------------------------------
1      | Walmart
```

I need to compare the EmployerName with CompanyName. If the names match then get some values. Otherwise, compare EmployerName with AliasList and get the some values. I need some help getting this work in `Linq` or `Linq To SQL`. The solution I tried:

```
var allAliasListData = getting all the AliasList values into a List by using split() function.

var result = from e in Empl
             from c in Company.Where(w => w.Company.Trim() == r.EmployerName.Trim() || allAliasListData.Contains(r.EmployerName.Trim())
```

Comment: If possible I'd recommend changing your DB design to put the aliases into a separate table (one row for each alias) and a one to many link back to the company table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to generate `List` for your both table. Then you can get your result using `Linq`. I've created an [example in DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8zWK4p) and the code example is below.

CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    class Company
    {
        public string CompanyID { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string AliasList { get; set; }
    }

    class Empl
    {
        public string EmplID { get; set; }
        public string EmployerName { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Case1();
        Case2();
        Case3();
    }

    static void Case1()
    {
        //CompanyName == EmployerName
        List<Empl> listEmpl = new List<Empl>() { new Empl() { EmplID = "1", EmployerName = "Walmart" } };
        List<Company> listCompany = new List<Company>() { new Company() { CompanyID = "1", CompanyName = "Walmart", AliasList = "Wal-mart;Wal Mart;Samsclub" } };

        var result = from e in listEmpl
            from c in listCompany.Where(w => w.CompanyName.Trim() == e.EmployerName.Trim() || w.AliasList.Split(';').Contains(e.EmployerName.Trim()))
            select new { c.CompanyName, e.EmployerName };

        if(result.FirstOrDefault() != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result.FirstOrDefault().CompanyName);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Result is empty!");
        }
    }

    static void Case2()
    {
        //AliasList Contain EmployerName
        List<Empl> listEmpl = new List<Empl>() { new Empl() { EmplID = "1", EmployerName = "Wal-mart" } };
        List<Company> listCompany = new List<Company>() { new Company() { CompanyID = "1", CompanyName = "Walmart", AliasList = "Wal-mart;Wal Mart;Samsclub" } };

        var result = from e in listEmpl
            from c in listCompany.Where(w => w.CompanyName.Trim() == e.EmployerName.Trim() || w.AliasList.Split(';').Contains(e.EmployerName.Trim()))
            select new { c.CompanyName, e.EmployerName };

        if(result.FirstOrDefault() != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result.FirstOrDefault().CompanyName);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Result is empty!");
        }
    }

    static void Case3()
    {
        //Not match any condition
        List<Empl> listEmpl = new List<Empl>() { new Empl() { EmplID = "1", EmployerName = "Wal - mart" } };
        List<Company> listCompany = new List<Company>() { new Company() { CompanyID = "1", CompanyName = "Walmart", AliasList = "Wal-mart;Wal Mart;Samsclub" } };

        var result = from e in listEmpl
            from c in listCompany.Where(w => w.CompanyName.Trim() == e.EmployerName.Trim() || w.AliasList.Split(';').Contains(e.EmployerName.Trim()))
            select new { c.CompanyName, e.EmployerName };

        if(result.FirstOrDefault() != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result.FirstOrDefault().CompanyName);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Result is empty!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks csharpbd. The suggested solution is very detailed and really helpful.